# Change simulator keyboard when performing XCUI tests

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

On my mac mini I have setup 2 different languages for my keyboard: English and Spanish. The reason is because I am using a Spanish keyboard. However when I do code and run UITest they language used is English.

My problem comes when I run the simulator. The keyboard language set is the one set on my mac mini so when I tried to find the soft keyboard return button "Next" I do it like that:

```
configuration.app.keyboards.buttons["Next"].tap().
```

Since the keyboard is automatically set to Spanish, the button can't be found because, in this case is:

```
configuration.app.keyboards.buttons["Siguiente"].tap()
```

To pass the UITests, I need to change the keyboard language on my mac mini which it's annoying. Is there any way to set English as standard keyboard when running UITests.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button shall have an identifier – e.g. "Search" button on keyboard has always `Search` identifier for all keyboard localisations.

"Shift" key identifies as `shift`.

"Symbols" as `more`.

The "Next" key as "Next:" – quite unexpected =)

You can tap this button with

`configuration.app.keyboards.buttons["Next:"].tap()`

You should use `print(configuration.app.debugDescription)` to find out identifiers you need.

Comment: So, are you saying that there is an identifier for the return button regardless the title ("Done", "Next"...) and the language?

Comment: Sorry for late reply "po print(app.debugDescription)" I saw what you meant

Answer (score 1):

I have been investigating what was going on. After doing

```
po print(app.debugDescription)
```

I saw

```
    t =    25.70s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 29553
    t =    26.08s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 29553
Optional(Attributes: Application, pid: 29553, label: 'Some'
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x600003f74b60, pid: 29553, label: 'Some'
    Window (Main), 0x600003f40700, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
      Other, 0x600003f40540, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
        Other, 0x600003f0a300, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
          Other, 0x600003f00700, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
            Other, 0x600003f74a80, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
              ScrollView, 0x600003f74c40, {{0.0, 44.0}, {375.0, 734.0}}
                Other, 0x600003f5a4c0, {{0.0, 44.0}, {375.0, 734.0}}
                  Image, 0x600003f5a840, {{62.7, 191.7}, {250.0, 72.0}}, identifier: 'General-logo'
                  Other, 0x600003f5a920, {{16.0, 295.7}, {343.0, 104.0}}
                    TextField, 0x600003f92ca0, {{16.0, 295.7}, {343.0, 52.0}}, placeholderValue: 'Email', value: johnsmith@Some..., Keyboard Focused
                      Button, 0x600003f5aae0, {{335.0, 312.7}, {19.0, 19.0}}, label: 'Clear text'
                    SecureTextField, 0x600003f5abc0, {{16.0, 347.7}, {343.0, 52.0}}, placeholderValue: 'Password'
                  Button, 0x600003f924c0, {{16.0, 431.7}, {343.0, 44.0}}, label: 'Log In', Disabled
                  Button, 0x600003f925a0, {{233.0, 491.7}, {126.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Forgot password?'
                  Other, 0x600003f0a3e0, {{0.0, 734.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
                    Other, 0x600003f92680, {{0.0, 734.0}, {375.0, 0.7}}
                    Other, 0x600003f92760, {{87.0, 742.0}, {201.0, 28.0}}
                      StaticText, 0x600003f92840, {{87.0, 742.0}, {144.0, 28.0}}, label: 'Don’t have an account?'
                      Button, 0x600003f92920, {{239.0, 742.0}, {49.0, 28.0}}, label: 'Sign Up'
    Window, 0x600003f0a4c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
      Other, 0x600003f407e0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
        Other, 0x600003f0a5a0, {{0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 335.0}}
          Other, 0x600003f63100, {{0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 277.0}}
    Window, 0x600003f40fc0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
      StatusBar, 0x600003f410a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
        Other, 0x600003f41180, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
          Other, 0x600003f41260, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
            Other, 0x600003f41340, {{6.0, -4.3}, {179.7, 10.7}}
            Other, 0x600003f41420, {{190.7, -4.3}, {179.3, 10.7}}
            Other, 0x600003f41500, {{6.0, 17.7}, {179.7, 10.7}}
            Other, 0x600003f415e0, {{13.3, 14.7}, {66.7, 13.7}}
              StaticText, 0x600003f416c0, {{30.0, 14.0}, {33.3, 18.0}}, label: '2:59 PM'
            Other, 0x600003f417a0, {{21.7, 8.7}, {54.7, 21.3}}
            Other, 0x600003f41880, {{190.7, 17.7}, {179.3, 10.7}}
            Other, 0x600003f41960, {{294.0, 14.7}, {66.7, 13.7}}
              Other, 0x600003f41a40, {{294.0, 17.7}, {17.0, 10.7}}, label: 'Cellular', value: No signal
              Other, 0x600003f41b20, {{316.0, 17.3}, {15.3, 11.0}}, identifier: '3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars', value: SSID, 3 of 3 Wi-Fi...
              Other, 0x600003f41c00, {{336.3, 17.3}, {24.3, 11.3}}, label: '100% battery power', value: Not charging
            Other, 0x600003f41ce0, {{294.0, 14.7}, {66.7, 13.7}}
          Other, 0x600003f41dc0, {{8.7, 24.7}, {81.3, 13.3}}
    Window, 0x600003f41ea0, {{-0.0, -0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
      Other, 0x600003f41f80, {{-0.0, -0.0}, {375.0, 812.0}}
        Other, 0x600003f42060, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 335.0}}
          Other, 0x600003f42140, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 277.0}}
            Other, 0x600003f42220, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 335.0}}
              Other, 0x600003f42300, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 335.0}}
                Other, 0x600003f423e0, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 335.0}}
          Other, 0x600003f424c0, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 277.0}}
            Keyboard, 0x600003f425a0, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 277.0}}
              Other, 0x600003f42680, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 277.0}}
                Other, 0x600003f42760, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'Typing Predictions'
                  Other, 0x600003f42840, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
                    Image, 0x600003f42920, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}
                  Other, 0x600003f42a00, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {123.0, 44.0}}
                  Other, 0x600003f42ae0, {{125.0, 477.0}, {125.0, 44.0}}
                  Other, 0x600003f42bc0, {{252.0, 477.0}, {123.0, 44.0}}
                  Other, 0x600003f42ca0, {{123.0, 491.0}, {1.0, 25.0}}
                  Other, 0x600003f42d80, {{250.0, 491.0}, {1.0, 25.0}}
                Other, 0x600003f42e60, {{-0.0, 521.0}, {375.0, 233.0}}
                  Key, 0x600003f42f40, {{-0.0, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'q'
                  Key, 0x600003f43020, {{37.5, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'w'
                  Key, 0x600003f43100, {{75.0, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'e'
                  Key, 0x600003f431e0, {{112.5, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'r'
                  Key, 0x600003f432c0, {{150.0, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 't'
                  Key, 0x600003f433a0, {{187.5, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'y'
                  Key, 0x600003f43480, {{225.0, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'u'
                  Key, 0x600003f43560, {{262.5, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'i'
                  Key, 0x600003f43640, {{300.0, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'o'
                  Key, 0x600003f43720, {{337.5, 528.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'p'
                  Key, 0x600003f43800, {{-0.0, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'a'
                  Key, 0x600003f438e0, {{37.5, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 's'
                  Key, 0x600003f439c0, {{75.0, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'd'
                  Key, 0x600003f43aa0, {{112.5, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'f'
                  Key, 0x600003f43b80, {{150.0, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'g'
                  Key, 0x600003f43c60, {{187.5, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'h'
                  Key, 0x600003f43d40, {{225.0, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'j'
                  Key, 0x600003f43e20, {{262.5, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'k'
                  Key, 0x600003f43f00, {{300.0, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'l'
                  Key, 0x600003f0c0e0, {{337.5, 582.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'ñ'
                  Button, 0x600003f06ae0, {{-0.0, 636.0}, {48.0, 46.0}}, identifier: 'shift', label: 'mayúsculas'
                  Key, 0x600003f06920, {{56.0, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'z'
                  Key, 0x600003f06a00, {{93.5, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'x'
                  Key, 0x600003f06bc0, {{131.0, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'c'
                  Key, 0x600003f15b20, {{169.0, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'v'
                  Key, 0x600003f94000, {{206.5, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'b'
                  Key, 0x600003f940e0, {{244.0, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'n'
                  Key, 0x600003f941c0, {{281.5, 636.0}, {37.5, 46.0}}, label: 'm'
                  Key, 0x600003f942a0, {{327.0, 636.0}, {48.0, 46.0}}, identifier: 'delete', label: 'Suprimir'
                  Key, 0x600003f94380, {{-0.0, 690.0}, {93.5, 46.0}}, identifier: 'more', label: 'más, números'
                  Key, 0x600003f94460, {{93.0, 690.0}, {94.5, 46.0}}, label: 'espacio'
                  Key, 0x600003f94540, {{187.5, 690.0}, {47.0, 46.0}}, label: '@'
                  Key, 0x600003f94620, {{234.5, 690.0}, {47.0, 46.0}}, label: '.'
                  Button, 0x600003f94700, {{281.5, 690.0}, {93.5, 46.0}}, identifier: 'Next:', label: 'Siguiente'
          Other, 0x600003f947e0, {{-0.0, 477.0}, {375.0, 335.0}}
            Button, 0x600003f948c0, {{-0.0, 745.0}, {66.0, 66.0}}, label: 'Next keyboard', value: English (US)
            Button, 0x600003f949a0, {{309.0, 745.0}, {66.0, 66.0}}, identifier: 'dictation', label: 'Dictate'
              StaticText, 0x600003f94a80, {{309.0, 745.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}
              Image, 0x600003f94b60, {{334.0, 761.0}, {15.0, 25.0}}, identifier: 'dictation_dockitem-portrait'
Path to element:
 →Application, pid: 29553, label: 'Some'
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 'some'
  Output: {
    Application, pid: 29553, label: 'Some'
  }
)
```

where I found as Smart Monkey suggested:

```
Button, 0x600003f94700, {{281.5, 690.0}, {93.5, 46.0}}, identifier: 'Next:', label: 'Siguiente'
```

The annoying part is the inconsistency. For instance, the button "Go":

```
Button, 0x600003f98460, {{281.5, 690.0}, {93.5, 46.0}}, identifier: 'Go', label: 'Ir', Disabled
```

No ":" on the identifier...

Comment: Yes, it is quite strange. Probably some other button somewhere in iOS already have this identifier.

Comment: printing the debug description helped me